# pygtk creating error on inheritance with treewiew and container.add

Tags: inheritance, python-2.7, pygtk

I am using python and pygtk

I have a class that inherits the TreeView class:

```
from gtk import TreeView
class FolderView(TreeView):
```

But when I add it to an HBox container:

```
folderView = FolderView
hbox.add(folderView)
```

I get the following error at runtime

```
TypeError: Gtk.Container.add() argument 1 must be gtk.Widget, not GObjectMeta
```

Through reflection, I have confirmed that gtk.Widget is in the inheritance path, so in my head it should work. Can anybody tell me which part of Python and pygtk I am not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `folderView = FolderView()`. See the following interactive prompt results:

```python
>>> from gtk import TreeView
>>> class FolderView(TreeView):
...     pass
... 
>>> fw = FolderView()
>>> from gtk import HBox
>>> hbox = HBox()
>>> hbox.add(FolderView) # this is passing the class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Gtk.Container.add() argument 1 must be gtk.Widget, not GObjectMeta
>>> hbox.add(FolderView()) # and this is actually creating an instance
>>> hbox.get_children()
[<FolderView object at 0x9ab1964 (GtkTreeView at 0x992a240)>]
```

Comment: I am blushing .... I totally missed that it was not instantiated. Guess it's a little to late for me, and I should go to bed. Thank you for your help.